# How to write CData in xml

Tags: c#, xml

i have an xml like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
    <entry_id></entry_id>
    <entry_status></entry_status>
  </entry>
```

i am writing data in it like:

```
XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("entry/entry_status");
xnode.InnerText = "<![CDATA[ " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["story_status"]) + " ]]>" ;
```

but its change "<" to "&lt" of CDATA.
Please tell me how to fill values in above xml as a CData format.

i know that we can create CDATA like :

```
XmlNode itemDescription = doc.CreateElement("description");
XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection("<P>hello world</P>");
itemDescription.AppendChild(cdata);
item.AppendChild(itemDescription);
```

but my process is to read node of xml and change its value not to append in it.
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you *really* need it to be in CDATA, or do you just want to get the text in there in a way which won't require extra escaping in your code?

`InnerText` performs whatever escaping is required, so generally I'd just use

```
xnode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["story_status"]);
```

... but if you *really* want a [CDATA node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcdatasection.aspx), you can create one yourself as per Nekresh's answer.

Comment: Great that mean the way i am performing writing in xml. the excape character will automatically handled and the xml reader will not face any issue and my xml will not break..right?

Comment: @Rajesh: Exactly. You can tell that setting the `InnerText` property performs escaping because that's exactly why your current approach doesn't work - it's escaping the text "<![CDATA[" for you!

Answer (score 24):

As described here: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx)

```
// Create an XmlCDataSection from your document
var cdata = xdoc.CreateCDataSection(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["story_status"]));

// Append the cdata section to your node
xnode.AppendChild(cdata);
```

Comment: I dont wants to append. i wants to change its value.. elements are already there

Answer (score 14):

If you really need a CDATA section (see [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679543/how-to-write-cdata-in-xml/4679585#4679585)), you can achieve that like so:

```
XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("entry/entry_status"); 
XmlCDataSection cdata = xdoc.CreateCDataSection(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["story_status"]));
xnode.InnerXml = cdata.OuterXml;
```

This will *replace* the contents of `xnode`, not append to it.

Answer (score 6):

Use Node.InnerXml, not Node.InnerText. Node.InnerText is automatically replacing special values. Note that if you specify with CDATA in InnerXml, then Node.InnerText is text in CDATA.
Example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string xmlTxt = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<entry>
    <entry_id></entry_id>
    <entry_status></entry_status>
  </entry>";
        TextReader treader = new StringReader(xmlTxt);
        XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(treader);
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(xreader);

        XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("entry/entry_status");
        //xnode.InnerText = "<![CDATA[something]]>";
        xnode.InnerXml = "<![CDATA[something]]>";
        Console.WriteLine("inner text is: " + xnode.InnerText);

        xdoc.Save(Console.Out); Console.WriteLine();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Program's output:

```
inner text is: something
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm852"?>
<entry>
  <entry_id>
  </entry_id>
  <entry_status><![CDATA[something]]></entry_status>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
XmlNode childNode = node.ChildNodes[0];
if (childNode is XmlCDataSection)
{
    XmlCDataSection cdataSection = childNode as XmlCDataSection;
    cdataSection.Value = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writer.WriteCData(value);`

where writer is `XmlWriter` object.