# Importing ONIX XML as a dataset ignoring HTML tags

Tags: .net, xml

Some time ago I wrote a procedure for importing ONIX files into a retail database system. (ONIX is an XML standard used by publishers for publishing their catalogue information.) The procedure imports the XML files directly into a dataset, and works well enough for most files we receive, but there are occasional exceptions.
In this particular case, the file I'm trying to import includes HTML tags in a product description field, which play havoc with the standard Dataset.ReadXML() method because it tries to interpret the HTML tags as XML. Some ONIX files include CDATA tags which avoid this problem, however in this case the publisher has chosen to use a tag attribute to designate that the field is in HTML format, like this:

```
    <othertext>
        <d102>03</d102>
        <d104 textformat="05">
            <p>Enter a world where bloody battles, and heroic deeds combine in the historic struggle to unite Britain in the face of a common enemy.</p>
            <p>The third instalment in Bernard Cornwell’s King Alfred series, follows on from the outstanding previous novels The Last Kingdom and The Pale Horseman.</p>
            <p>The year is 878 and the Vikings have been thrown out of Wessex. Uhtred, fresh from fighting for Alfred in the battle to free Wessex, travels north to seek revenge for his father's death, killed in a bloody raid by Uhtred's old enemy, renegade Danish lord, Kjartan.</p>
            <p>While Kjartan lurks in his formidable stronghold of Dunholm, the north is overrun by chaos, rebellion and fear. Together with a small band of warriors, Uhtred plans his attack on his enemy, revenge fuelling his anger, resolute on bloody retribution. But, he finds himself betrayed and ends up on a desperate slave voyage to Iceland. Rescued by a remarkable alliance of old friends and enemies, he and his allies, together with Alfred the Great, are free to fight once more in a battle for power, glory and honour.</p>
            <p>‘The Lords of the North’ is a tale of England's making, a powerful story of betrayal, struggle and romance, set in an England torn apart by turmoil and upheaval.</p>
        </d104>
    </othertext>
```

The textformat="05" attribute indicates HTML.

Without writing custom code for interpreting the HTML, is it possible to still import this using ReadXML(), or do I need to programmatically insert CDATA tags first to work around it?

NOTE: I don't want to strip out the HTML tags, as the data will appear on a web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program in [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) that should find the textformat=05 nodes and wrap their content in CData sections.  See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679543/how-to-write-cdata-in-xml)

```
void Main()
{
    string xml = @"<othertext>
            <d102>03</d102>
            <d104 textformat=""05"">
                <p>Enter a world where bloody battles, and heroic deeds combine in the historic struggle to unite Britain in the face of a common enemy.</p>
                <p>The third instalment in Bernard Cornwell’s King Alfred series, follows on from the outstanding previous novels The Last Kingdom and The Pale Horseman.</p>
                <p>The year is 878 and the Vikings have been thrown out of Wessex. Uhtred, fresh from fighting for Alfred in the battle to free Wessex, travels north to seek revenge for his father's death, killed in a bloody raid by Uhtred's old enemy, renegade Danish lord, Kjartan.</p>
                <p>While Kjartan lurks in his formidable stronghold of Dunholm, the north is overrun by chaos, rebellion and fear. Together with a small band of warriors, Uhtred plans his attack on his enemy, revenge fuelling his anger, resolute on bloody retribution. But, he finds himself betrayed and ends up on a desperate slave voyage to Iceland. Rescued by a remarkable alliance of old friends and enemies, he and his allies, together with Alfred the Great, are free to fight once more in a battle for power, glory and honour.</p>
                <p>‘The Lords of the North’ is a tale of England's making, a powerful story of betrayal, struggle and romance, set in an England torn apart by turmoil and upheaval.</p>
            </d104>
        </othertext>";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//othertext/*[@textformat='05']");
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var cdata = xmlDoc.CreateCDataSection(node.InnerXml);
        node.InnerText = string.Empty;
        node.AppendChild(cdata);
        node.InnerXml.Dump(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick! the only adjustment I had to make was to the following line (note the double-slash):

`var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//othertext/*[@textformat='05']");`