# How to set "&#xA;" to XML Document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, escaping, xmldocument, innertext

I want to set `"&#xA;"` to Xml file.But my below chord Unintentionally changed \n.
Can I set `"&#xA;"` in XML File?
please teach me.

```
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in secondNode)
        {
            if (xnode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xnode.Name == "element")
            {
                string line1 = model.Second.CommentList[j].Line1;
                string line2 = model.Second.CommentList[j].Line2;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line2))
                {
                    xnode.InnerXml = line1;
                }
                else
                {
                    xnode.InnerXml = line1 + "&#xA;" + line2;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        outputStream.Position = 0;
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream))
        {
            doc.WriteTo(xw);
        }
        outputStream.Flush();
        outputStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Either set InnerText or add a CDATA node: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679543/how-to-write-cdata-in-xml

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work.Is there other way? Because if using CDATA, I need to decode InnerText when reading xml file.

Comment: There's no semantic difference between the two. `&#xA;` is the 'entitized' version of `\n`. Is there any particular reason you care?

Comment: Looks like you have an issue where your code reads xml data and you try to solve that by how you *write* the xml data.

Comment: I know threre's no differenc between two.
The File Specification write this format  that is"&#xA;".
I think just only looking...