# Converting SOAP XMLString to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

[Question Modified] I am completely new to XML and am calling a web service(WCF). The request is expected to be in the below format:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:CreateLead>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:xDoc>
            <lead>
            <![CDATA[<CreateLead>

<FIRSTNAME>John</FIRSTNAME>
<LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
<MOBILE>9999999999</MOBILE>
<EMAIL>john@doe.com</EMAIL>
<SOURCE>Website</SOURCE>
<SUBSOURCE>Blog</SUBSOURCE>
<WEBREMARKS></WEBREMARKS>
<TIMETOCALL>26/02/2018 18:40:15 PM</TIMETOCALL>
<FAILEDSTEP>Step 1</FAILEDSTEP>
<FOILIONO>123</FOILIONO>
<SCHEMECODE>123</SCHEMECODE>
<AMOUNT>100</AMOUNT>
<REGEVENT></REGEVENT>
<FEEDBACK></FEEDBACK>
</CreateLead>
]]>
            </lead>
         </tem:xDoc>
      </tem:CreateLead>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have created the proxy class and the below is the signature of the method to be called:

```
public System.Xml.XmlElement CreateLead(System.Xml.XmlElement xDoc)
{
    return base.Channel.CreateLead(xDoc);
}
```

I am passing the complete SOAP as a string literal and converting it into an XMLElement and am getting a proper response. I wish to pass it as a C# object. Is there a way to create a class according to my above SOAP request?

I tried copying the XML and using Visual Studio's paste special to Paste XML as class but it is somehow not creating an exact replica of the above mentioned SOAP XML.

I need it to be completely similar to the above SOAP format.

Please help.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing the `<![CDATA[` part?

Comment: Tried that. Getting an exception at doc.LoadXml(xml) itself.

Comment: You added it in the textbox, right? I think you need to create a CDataNode and add tmpXmlElement to that as a child. Then provide that to CreateLead.

Comment: Yes. I added it in the textbox. Can you please help with the code to add it as a child.

Comment: Sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4679571/982149

Comment: Thanks.
The trick of passing the entire content right from <soapenv:Envelope did the trick. Now I have another question. I have modified the above question according to it. Please help.